# How to specify multiple bundle paths in Swift without repeating code?

Tags: swift, xcode, path, bundle, plist

Possibly a simple question, how do I specify multiple bundle paths for swift to read without having to copy paste this code multiple times?

```
 if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "extra-1", ofType: "plist") {
        if let dictArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
            for item in dictArray {
                if let dict = item as? NSDictionary {
                    let name = dict["identifier"] as! String
                    let species = dict["species"] as! Int

                    let animal = Animal(name: name, speciesId: species)
                    pokes.append(animal)
                    print("Name: \(name) Id: \(species)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want swift to access the same dict items from multiple plist files, but so far my only solution is to repeat this code for 17+ files. Any held would be appreciative

Comment: Wait, why is species an Int? O.o'

Comment: it returns the species number. The order it is to be displayed. And sorry I'm not too adept at Swift coding, I don't know what you mean by 'CustomStringRepresentable' conformance

Comment: The species might be better modeled with an `enum`. As with all things you don't know about that I mentioned, just look it up, and come back here to ask any questions you might have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
extension Animal {
    init(fromDict dict: [String: Any]) {
        self.init(
            name: dict["identifier"] as! String,
            species: dict["species"] as! Int
        )
    }
}

let resourceNames = [
    "extra-1",  "extra-2", /* ... */  "extra-n"
]

let pokes = resourceNames.flatMap { resourceName -> [Animal] in
    guard let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resourceName, ofType: "plist") else {
        fatalError("Nil path") //TODO: add error handling!
    }
    guard let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: plistPath) else { fatalError("File read error") }

    let arrayOfDicts = array.map{ element -> [String: Any] in
        guard let dict = element as? [String: Any] else { fatalError("Element is not a dictionary!") }
        return dict
    }

    let newPokes = arrayOfDicts.map(Animal.init(fromDict:))
    print(newPokes)
    return newPokes
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Im getting an error "Unable to infer complex closure return types' on this line -----> let pokes = resourceNames.flatMap { resourceName in guard let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resourceName, ofType: "plist")

Comment: @user4938361 Fixed

Comment: I had actually already corrected that line before commenting. The error seems to be unrelated. Also, I can't use the extension unless I add "convenience" in front the initializer because --> "the designated init could not be declared in an extension". I'm using Swift 3 if that helps

Comment: Thanks but, it seems from what I'm researching, I cannot use this type of inheritance method with Swift

Comment: @user4938361 There is no inheritance going on. Yeah, that init should be marked `convenience`. Though it might make sense to just move that initializer into the body of the `Animal` struct

Comment: Inheritance was the wrong word, yes, but I can't get rid of the compile error "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate"

Comment: The final result compiles! But there are 2 issues. It returns "AnimalDex.Animals" on the console instead of the animal names/ids. also "value poke was never used?"

Comment: If animal is a class, then you need to add your own conformance to `CustomStringRepresentable`, to get it to print however you want.

Comment: Why are you appending the new entries when flatmap does exactly that? O.o'?

Comment: Thank you!! It works after adding **pokes.append(newPokes)'**before **return newPokes**. I still can't get it to print the results on the console but the results print fine in the CollectionViewCell

Comment: It doesn't display in the CollectionViewCell when I don't append them

Comment: Well you obviously have to assign the result of the flatmap expression to wherever you need them. I made the local variable `pokes`, you'll need to change that to assign wherever you need it

Comment: Ok, I'll eventually figure it all out. Thank you!!